# How do I pass my javascript variable to an option value in a dropdown?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

I've got a database containing a "home" position of a user in lat and long lattitudes, I just need to know how to pass these values to a drop down in order for the following code to work:

The code is here: 
http://pastebin.com/sVf214Qs

I can't get the code formatted on here properly sorry.
Thanks in advance if you can get this working

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you do

```
<option value="<?php echo $lat . ', ' . $long; ?>">Home</option>
```

Just as you do later in your page?

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" id="lat" name="lat" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $long; ?>" id="long" name="long" />
```

Comment: Thankyou! I think I may have been going the long way around this?